# Parameters and Ranges of Values

Tags: crystal-reports, reporting

I need to create a report in Crystal 2008 and I've haven't developed a report using Crystal in  many years.

When the user runs the report, I want them to be able to enter a start date and end date. I assume I can do this by using parameters. My question is this. Can I do this with a single parameter value or will it require two parameter values? Ideally what I would like to do is to  allow the user to enter a start and end date in one parameter/prompt combination. Is this possible?

Thanks - Randy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible and what your talking about is a ranged parameter value.

1. Create an parameter in Crystal Reports
2. set the type to Date
3. In the options Area.  you will see a option called Allow range values.  Set this to true.